# int-array initialized from non-wide string when trying to make tchar

Tags: c, tchar

I'm trying to make a tchar array here like this:
 TCHAR c_wText[100] = _T("string here");

But on compilation I'm getting an error message:
int-array initialized from non-wide string

Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you show your `#include` file list please. *in the question; not here in a comment*. (and just for kicks, try using `TEXT("string here")` instead).

Comment: What if you put an `L` before the string (so `_T(L"string here");`)

Comment: @slugonamission interesting thought. Especially considering the `_T()` macro is supposed to do precisely that, assuming he's compiling Unicode, which he should be if `TCHAR` is wide.

Comment: _T(L"string here"); seems to work, thanks!

Comment: @Vanguard if it does, its wrong. That macro is *supposed* to prepend the `L` for you in Unicode builds. Is there any chance you accidently removed one of the preprocessor Unicode #define's from your preprocessor list? There are two, UNICODE and _UNICODE. One is used for the Windows API, the other for the CRT. You need to check them both, as this won't be the only thing broken if they're not congruent.

Comment: Well I don't know, I'm trying to use a sendkeys, if i wrote a code like this:

`sk.SendKeys("{appactivate Firefox}^v", false);`

candidate for first arg is TCHAR* and obviosly, I don't know how to make it properly

So yeah, I didn't defined anything

Comment: @Vanguard are you using Visual Studio?, and if so what version?

Comment: I'm not using it, that's the problem, i'm using qt

Comment: @Vanguard ok. that makes sense. and its not really a problem. if `_T("string")` fails to be compatible with `TCHAR`, `LPTSTR`, etc., and the complaint it because the literal is a non-wide string, then likely  it is because `_UNICODE` is not defined (for the CRT) but `UNICODE` is (for the Windows API headers). The Windows API equivalent is `TEXT("string")`, in case you wanted to just stick with API-defs, whihc honestly isn't terribly uncommon

Comment: ok, so `text` macro seems to work, but now i'm getting an undefined reference to `CSendKeys::CSendKeys()`
`undefined reference to CSendKeys(wchar_t const*, bool)` when i'm sending tchar array like this:
`TCHAR c_wText[100] = TEXT(L"{appactivate Firefox}^v");
 sk.SendKeys(c_wText, false); 
`

Comment: Guess I should've used a Visual Studio instead

Comment: @Vanguard no no. DON'T include a prepended `L`"" to your string constants if you put them inside `TEXT()` or `_T()` macros. Maybe I didn't make that clear. The macros do it **for you** if compiling as Unicode; **you should never have to have something that looks like this:** `TEXT(L"string value")`. It should look like **this:** `TEXT("string value")`. Note **NO `L` prepending the string if it is inside the `TEXT()` macro.** If you find you have to put `L` in front of a string in a `TEXT` or `_T` macro, then either you shouldn't be using the macro, or somethings WRONG in your preproc defs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm summarizing what @WhozCraig kindly said:

For unicode builds you need both UNICODE and _UNICODE defined

then use TCHAR and _T("your string")